# Missing step in proof?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was just looking over my notes and found that some steps, while obvious, seem to be missing in-between steps. For example:

$$x ∈ S \land (x ∈ T \lor x ∈ V) \Rightarrow (x ∈ S \land x ∈ T) \lor (x ∈ S \land x ∈ V)$$

Now this step seems intuitive. I mean, if $x$ belongs to $S$ and $x$ either belongs to $T$ or $V$, then obviously either $x$ belongs to $S$ and $T$, or $x$ belongs to $S$ and $V$.

But given that the previous steps were just converting from $x ∈ S ∩ (T ∪ V)$ to $x ∈ S \land (x ∈ T \lor x ∈ V)$, it seems like a lot more is being done in this step than simply following definitions of union and intersection. Therefore, is this step missing an intermediate step? Or is there a logical principle that I'm not aware of that allows this to happen in one step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the distributive property of unions and intersections. Or equivalently, that of "and" and "or."

Comment: Actually, the distributive property of logical "or" and "and." We don't know what he is trying to prove, but he might be trying to prove the distributive law of unions and intersections.

Comment: yes that is what I'm trying to prove. Don't we first have to prove the distributive property of or and and before we can use it as a step in the proof though?

Comment: I would expect that you've proven that in a set theory and mathematical logic course already, as it is foundational.

Comment: I might have, but you still have to include it for the proof to be complete, right?

Comment: Of course not, if you have proven a theorem, you can use it. We don't need to show that "and" distributes over "or" every time the idea comes up in mathematics. You can mention that it has been previously shown, but I don't think it is necessary for something like this (though it is not a bad idea.)

Comment: If you were writing a standalone proof for a computer to read, you'd have to include the proof, but not for human consumption - you just point to the fact that you have proven it already. @user2108462